Php is installed but not loading in 24.04
So, I have Apache2 installed and after upgrading from 23.10 apparently PHP code is shown in the browser rather than executing.
I installed php8.3, and tried loading the module to get this error.
root@p7-1268c:/var/www/html# a2enmod php
ERROR: Module php does not exist!

How do I fix this?

After messing around, these commands worked as sudo.
a2dismod mpm_event
a2enmod php8.3
systemctl restart apache2


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
